# Custom method with jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Im trying to work with custom validation in Jquery. All the coding part is right,but i am not getting where its going wrong...here is the part of code.

```
Password:<input type="password" id="pnameTxt" name="pnameTxt" placeholder="Enter Password" size=12 class='required'><br>
Confirm Password:<input type="password" id="pnameTxt2" name="pnameTxt2" placeholder="Retype Password" size=15 class='required passwordCheck'><br>
```

Custom validation method:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("passwordCheck",function (value,element){
          return value==$("#pnameTxt").val(); 

        }, 'Password and Confirm Password should be same');
```

Comment: No need to write a custom method.  Just use the `equalTo` rule.  See:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/equalTo#other

Answer (score 34):

Your code is working.  You also have to assign the rule to your field when you initialize the plugin with `.validate()`.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/KrLkF/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod("passwordCheck", function (value, element) {
        return value == $("#pnameTxt").val();
    }, 'Password and Confirm Password should be same');

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            pnameTxt2: {
                passwordCheck: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

---

**HOWEVER**, you do not need to write a custom method for this functionality.  The jQuery Validate plugin already has an [`equalTo` rule](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/equalTo#other), and here's how to use it.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/tdhHt/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            pnameTxt2: {
                equalTo: "#pnameTxt" // using `id` of the other field
            }
        },
        messages: {
            pnameTxt2: {
                equalTo: "Password and Confirm Password should be same"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have u initialized the validation plugin correctly?
When  I put the html in a `form` and then `initialize the plugin` it works as expected.

```
<form id="test">
Password:<input type="password" id="pnameTxt" name="pnameTxt" placeholder="Enter Password" size=12 class='required'><br>
Confirm Password:<input type="password" id="pnameTxt2" name="pnameTxt2" placeholder="Retype Password" size=15 class='required passwordCheck'><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

```js
$.validator.addMethod("passwordCheck",function (value,element){
      return value==$("#pnameTxt").val(); 

    }, 'Password and Confirm Password should be same');

$('#test').validate();
```

Comment: where i have to place  

$('#test').validate();

Comment: As inline code in the same file where your form is or with a reference to an external js file. And place it inside `$(document).ready(function() {
  //Your code
});` to be sure that the form is loaded when you call the plugin.